# Assigning a value to a certain array element

Tags: java, arrays

I need help with this little piece of code which I did not quite understand while reading a book about Java programming. Basically there are some pieces of code which is written for you to correct. I managed to correct some of the training exercises, but this one has made me confused..

"The following code segment should assign the value 10 to the array element that corresponds to the third row and the fourth column."

```
int[] a[] = new int[10][5];

a[2][3] = 10;
```

So this is the code which is written in the book. How is it supposed to look if I actually correct it? Quite confused of what they actually mean, so if someone could explain I what they mean, I would really appreciate it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if that is the full question, then it is incomplete. A 2d array can either be [`row-major`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) or `column-major`. Without know which it is, then you cannot answer that question. That is the correct code for a `row-major` implementation while for `column-major` you have to flip the indexes.

```
a[3][2] = 10;
```

Comment: Yeah that is what I was confused over..This if the full question as stated in the book which made me wonder..Thank you for explaining.

Comment: @Smit the memory may always be laid out the same way, but it also lays it out flat in memory as memory has no sense of rows/columns. In programming languages it is the same concept as mathematically, but it is not how it is stored, but how it is used.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there's a typo with the first line, assignment should be:

```
int[][] a = new int[10][5];
a[3][2]  = 10;
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Your code with this line won't compile. `int[] a` should be `int[][] a`.

Comment: Right @Smit I did a typo too. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect, it should be:

```
int[][] a = new int[10][5];
a[3][2]  = 10;
```